# Copy a file from n-number of bytes to n-number of bytes buffered

Tags: java

Consider this code:

```
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/gala/falken_test/test_file"));
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/home/gala/falken_test/out"));

int b;
byte[] buff = new byte[8096];
while ((b = bufferedInputStream.read(buff)) > -1) {
    bufferedOutputStream.write(buff, 0, b);
    System.out.println("Writing " + b);
}

bufferedInputStream.close();
bufferedOutputStream.close();
```

This copies a file from point A (`bufferedInputStream`) to point B (`bufferedOutputStream`), `8096` bytes at a time, untill the last try is larger than the file itself, then it trims the buffer and reads the remaining data. This looks like this, this is the output from `System.out.println("Writing " + b);`

```
Writing 8096
Writing 8096

    ...

Writing 8096
Writing 8096
Writing 5681

This took 14 ms
```

Now the problem rises that, how can I copy a certain range of bytes?

For example, from `1012` bytes to `2134`, if the file is `10000` bytes long for example.

What I an writing is a tar implementation, where a lot of files get concatenated one to other with a `512` byte header between them, which describes the bytes following the header.

And I read the header, skip 512 bytes of the header and start writing the file, until n-bytes of data, which are specified in the header.

How can I solve this without copying byte-by-byte?

Comment: Are you looking for `java.util.RandomAccessFile`?

Comment: Please refer to [`Random Access File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html)

Comment: I have read some documentation, and Random Access File does allow me to specify the start, but not the end. If I add a if statement in the while body, the loop over-reads over the needed bytes, as it adds 8096 bytes at a time.

Comment: from the Javadoc:

`int java.io.FilterInputStream.read(byte[] b) throws IOException

Reads up to byte.length bytes of data from this input stream into an array of bytes. This method blocks until some input is available.

This method simply performs the call read(b, 0, b.length) and returns the result. It is important that it does not do in.read(b) instead;` 


And `read(b, 0, b.length)` will call `private int read1(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException` which reads bytewise.

Comment: I can not instantiate FilterOutputStream, its constructor is protected??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`BufferedInputStream.skip(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) to skip until right pos, and the read and write the amount of bytes from `1012` (`startPos`) to `2134` (`endPos`), that is `2134-1012=1122` bytes.

*Note*: I changed the buffer size to 512 instead to show how it works with your example positions.

```
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("test_file"));
    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test_out"));

    int CHUNK_SIZE = 512; // change to 8096
    int startPos = 1012;
    int endPos = 2134;
    int bytesToRead = endPos - startPos;
    int b;
    byte[] buff = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
    bufferedInputStream.skip(startPos - 1);
    int currentChunkSize = Math.min(CHUNK_SIZE, bytesToRead);
    while ((b = bufferedInputStream.read(buff, 0, currentChunkSize)) != -1) {
        bufferedOutputStream.write(buff, 0, b);
        System.out.println("Writing " + b);
        bytesToRead -= b;
        if (bytesToRead == 0) {
            break;
        }
        currentChunkSize = Math.min(CHUNK_SIZE, bytesToRead);
    }

    bufferedInputStream.close();
    bufferedOutputStream.close();
```

The output from this is:

```
$ java -cp ReadWriteTest    
Writing 512
Writing 512
Writing 98
```

Comment: This is perfect! I will adopt it to a RandomAccesFile and use seek() instead of skip. Nice!

Comment: Cool! One thing I was thinking about, make sure you are not reading more than `8096` bytes if  `(endPos - startPos - bytesRead) > 8096` :)

Comment: Yes that is the new issue, the buffer becomes too big. What now?

Comment: Answer now updated to handle that also, note that I have `CHUNK_SIZE = 512` instead of `8096`. So just change that in you use case.